# How to use another class as a class template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have a hybrid-lock class that spin tries a lock for a (compile time fixed) number of spins before falling back to blocking on a `std::mutex` until the lock becomes available.

Simplified:

```
#include <mutex>

template<unsigned SPIN_LIMIT>
class hybrid_lock {
public:
    void lock(){
        for(unsigned i(0);i<SPIN_LIMIT;++i){
            if(this->mMutex.try_lock()){
                return;        
            }
        } 
        this->mMutex.lock();
    }
    void unlock(){
        this->mMutex.unlock();
    }
private:
    std::mutex mMutex;
};
```

In the special case of `SPIN_LIMIT==0` this falls back to being a 'plain' `std::mutex` (i.e. no *visible* spins).

So I've specialized that to:

```
template<>
class hybrid_lock<0> : public std::mutex {};
```

It works fine but is that the approved way of specializing class templates to be another (pre-existing) template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* I answered the actual question rather than the one in the title.

Well, now `hybird_lock<0>` and `hybird_lock<1>` are quite something different, one derives from `std::mutex` and the other contains/wraps it. This changes whole constiution of `hybird_lock` and meaning behind it. I.e. they are not semantically the same. This might led to some rather unexpected consequences -`hybird_lock<0>` would inherit a whole lot of stuff, which other cases wouldn't have.

If that's the only difference I would not bother with specialization at all. Remember the zero-case will be known at compile time, and as certainly as it gets, the whole loop will be completely optimized out.

If there were other important (or actual) optimizations, I'd would go for something like:

```
template<>
class hybrid_lock<0> {
public:
    void lock(){
      this->mMutex.lock();
    }
    void unlock(){
      this->mMutex.unlock();
    }
private:
    std::mutex mMutex;
};
```

This implementation makes `0` a special case, rather than something almost completely different.

Comment: I agree the point. For example you could pass an instance of `hybrid_lock<0>` to functions expecting a reference to `std::mutex` but the same isn't true of `hybrid_lock<n>` all other `n`.  That could cause programs to 'break by tuning' which is never a pretty sight. NB: The real hybrid class is more complicated than the one shown and a compiler can't be expected to spot the simplification. Maybe that is the answer 'don't' use trivial containment and forwarding.

Comment: @DanAllen That was exactly my point, there is quite more to it, like behaviour on copy, destruction, etc. Maybe for `std::mutex` there would be no side effects, but as a general pattern despite how much tempting this looks, it's probably not a good idea =). I'd go for reimplementation, or some more sophisticated way if necessary, like the answer by Roger suggests.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "official" way to do it, but here is a good way - with templates it's often a better idea to break the main template class down into smaller 'action' or 'function' template classes. This way you get more control and granularity over specialisation, which means you only have to maintain the main logic in one place:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

// general form of the spin_locker
template<unsigned SPIN_LIMIT, class Mutex>
struct spinner
{
    static void lock(Mutex& m) {
        for (unsigned i = 0 ; i < SPIN_LIMIT ; ++i)
            if (m.try_lock())
                return;
        m.lock();
    }
};

// optmised partial specialisation for zero spins
template<class Mutex>
struct spinner<0, Mutex>
{
    static void lock(Mutex& m) {
        m.lock();
    }

};

template<unsigned SPIN_LIMIT, class Mutex = std::mutex>
class hybrid_lock {

    using spinner_type = spinner<SPIN_LIMIT, Mutex>;

public:
    void lock(){
        spinner_type::lock(mMutex);
    }

    void unlock(){
        mMutex.unlock();
    }

    std::unique_lock<Mutex> make_lock() {
        return std::unique_lock<Mutex>(mMutex);
    }

private:
    Mutex mMutex;
};

// since only the 'spinner' functor object needs specialising there is now no need to specialise the main logic

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    hybrid_lock<100> m1;
    hybrid_lock<0> m2;
    hybrid_lock<100, std::recursive_mutex> m3;
    hybrid_lock<0, std::recursive_mutex> m4;

    auto l1 = m1.make_lock();
    auto l2 = m2.make_lock();
    auto l3 = m3.make_lock();
    auto l4 = m4.make_lock();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like this. Good spot that I should parameterize my Mutex class. My class only works with bog-standard `std::mutex`. Yours could be used with `recursive_mutex`  (and friends). I also like the 'slot in' partial specialization. The real case is actually more complicated than this and would end up with some redundant member variables. Though that's not necessarily a problem.

Comment: @DanAllen you can further eliminate those redundant member variables by breaking your class down into smaller and smaller logical components. The general form of these smaller logical components would hold the member variables, and the specialised versions of them may not. There are a number of advantages to this approach: easier unit testing, better logic encapsulation and perfect efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Richard Hodges answer is great, but you can simply overload method `lock`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <mutex>

template<class Mutex = std::mutex>
struct hybrid_lock {
    template<int N>
    void lock(std::integral_constant<int, N> val){
        for (unsigned i = 0 ; i < val() ; ++i)
            if (mMutex.try_lock())
                return;
        mMutex.lock();
    }

    void lock(std::integral_constant<int, 0>){
        mMutex.lock();
    }

    void unlock(){
        mMutex.unlock();
    }

    std::unique_lock<Mutex> make_lock() {
        return std::unique_lock<Mutex>(mMutex);
    }

private:
    Mutex mMutex;
};

template <int N>
constexpr
std::integral_constant<int, N> IC;

int main() {

    hybrid_lock<> m1;
    hybrid_lock<> m2;

    m1.lock(IC<0>);
    m2.lock(IC<100>);
    return 0;
}
```

IC is [variable template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), from c++14, if your compiler doesn't support it you can use type alias [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead:

```
template<int N>
using IC = std::integral_constant<int, N>;
```

and use it like this

```
m.lock(IC<0>{});
```

Comment: I really like this too. I like the fact that it's parameterizing the 'spin-limit' to the call to lock(N). I have a 'textbook' producer/consumer model and I can imagine it might turn out that there should be different spin limits on the two sides of the fence. Why is this better than template<int N>void lock(); ? What is `std::integral_constant<int N>` adding?

Comment: It gives you ability to override template method for '0'. You may try to use `template <int N>` and specialize lock for N == 0, but since hybrid_lock is also template it may won't compile.